# DHIS data stored locally is not uploading to server (progress bar never completes)

Tags: dhis2, data, uploading

I have created data collection forms in a new instance of DHIS2 and am in the process of entering data for different org units.

However a yellow pop up is telling me that there is data stored locally that needs to be uploaded to the server - when I click upload it says "uploading locally stored data to the server" but the progress bar continues to cycle without end. Any ideas on what I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this means that there is some corrupted data in your browser cache (local database). The easiest fix is to clear your browser cache, including the application cache. You can learn how to do that in [this tutorial](https://www.dhis2.org/tutorials/how-to-really-clear-browser-cache).

You can also have a look in the Javascript console on Chrome and look for errors (in red text), and post your findings on the DHIS 2 [developer mailing list](https://www.dhis2.org/contact) in order to get help.